# Rotating a matrix counter-clockwise changes the original as well

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I currently have a function to rotate a matrix counter-clockwise, the list is always a square grid:

```
def rotate(m: List[List[int]]) -> None:
temp = m.copy()

if len(m) > 1:   
    for x in range(len(m)):
        for y in range(len(m)):
            temp[len(m)-1-y][x] = m[x][y]

m = temp.copy()
```

I've traced this function repeatedly and to my knowledge it should be working. The problem is that for some reason every change to temp affects the original list. For example,

```
ORIGINAL =

[[1, 2, 3], 

[4, 5, 6], 

[7, 8, 9]]

WHAT SHOULD OUTPUT = 

[[3, 6, 9], 

[2, 5, 8], 

[1, 4, 7]]

WHAT ACTUALLY OUTPUTS = 

[[3, 6, 1], 

[2, 5, 2], 

[1, 2, 1]
```

I am on python ver 3.7.0 and have tried slipicing instead of copying the string too but the same thing happens. Anyone know why?

Comment: What happens when you replace `temp = m.copy()` with `temp = deepcopy(m)` (of course you'll have to import `deepcopy`)?

Comment: Using deepcopy just outputs the original list back again for some reason. I tried using `temp = deepcopy(m)` and `m = temp.copy()` first, then used `deepcopy` on both but they both just output the original list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since every item in the `m` list is a reference to a sublist, when you make a copy of the `m` list by calling `m.copy()`, it is only copying the references of the sublists without creating new copies of the sublists, which is why every change to the `temp` list is reflected on the original `m` list.

You should use `copy.deepcopy()` instead to make copies of the sublists as well:

```
from copy import deepcopy
def rotate(m):
    temp = deepcopy(m)
    if len(m) > 1:
        for x in range(len(m)):
            for y in range(len(m)):
                temp[len(m)-1-y][x] = m[x][y]
    return temp
```

so that:

```
rotate([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])
```

returns:

```
[[3, 6, 9],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [1, 4, 7]]
```

Alternatively, you can implement the same matrix rotation by zipping the list of lists and reversing it:

```
def rotate(m):
    return list(zip(*m))[::-1]
```

Comment: I don't want to return anything for this function. And using deepcopy for both temp and then `m = deepcopy(temp)` doesnt change any values of m. I'm trying to rotate m with no return from the function.

Comment: Also, I haven't learned `deepcopy` in my class, so I don't wanna use anything new for this

Comment: out of curiosity would `temp = m.copy(deep = True)` be the same as `temp = deepcopy(m)`

Comment: @Albertgonzal If you don't want the function to return anything you can simply assign `temp` to `m` with `m = temp` in the end instead of `return temp`.

Comment: @blhsing I tried that but for some reason temp has the correct values but doing `m = temp` doesnt change m at all and m remains the original list :/

Comment: @Albertgonzal Ah indeed, I forgot that you can't change the caller's reference to `m` by assigning a local variable `m` to a new list. You should instead do `m[:] = temp`.

Comment: FINALLY, thank you so much, I changed my code a little so i wouldn't have to use `deepcopy` but this was the last step i needed. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy

def rotate(m: [[int]]):
    temp = copy.deepcopy(m)
    if len(m) > 1:
        for x in range(len(m)):
            for y in range(len(m)):
                temp[len(m)-1-y][x] = m[x][y]
    return temp
```

So:

```
rotate([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])
```

Output:

```
[[3, 6, 9],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [1, 4, 7]]
```

Example: https://onlinegdb.com/ryGU1jD6X